# Express JS way to clear memory with out shutting down server?

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have an express js server running.  The server has 4 gigs of memory.  Not the whole server is allocated to run express so it shares with other processes.

server.js code is:

```
// server.js
var webshot = require('./lib/webshot');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded() );

// your express configuration here
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
// For http
httpServer.listen(8080);


app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var firstLine = req.body.firstLine;
    var secondLine = req.body.secondLine;
    var previewID = req.body.previewId;
    var productPlate = req.body.prodName;
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://citylocs.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    takeWebshot(firstLine, secondLine, previewID, productPlate)
    .then(() => console.log("a process exit here kills the server"))
    res.end()
});

function takeWebshot(fLine, sLine, pID, prodPlate) {
    var options = {
      takeShotOnCallback: true,
      captureSelector: '#img_preview_fancybox',
      licensePlate: 'Guzman Plate'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    webshot('example.com/preview/productpreview/testy.html?prod=' + prodPlate, '../screenshot/' + pID +'.png', options, function(err) {
      if(!err) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  })
    const used = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log(used);
  };
```

In the above webshot goes to a url takes a screenshot and puts it in a file in my server.

I get the following results:

```
{ rss: 29876224,
  heapTotal: 18694144,
  heapUsed: 12250200,
  external: 390493 }
```

the memoryUsage usually returns about the same on multiple runs.
The server takes a request and then executes the code runs takewebshot() and then it completes.  My problem is after about 20 minutes of this the server crashes and has to be restarted, it runs out of memory and gives me an error.  Is there anything I can add to "clear memory" cache?  Quitting the process is not a solution cause then I have to restart the server.js file again.  I would like to avoid a reset of server.js.

Comment: There is no official method to "clear memory" as you say.  What you can do is to use heapSnapShots to determine if the memory your node.js process has allocated from the system is "in use" from something you're doing or some kind of memory leaks or free internally and ready to be reused (but not returned to the OS).  That would be your  first step.  With that info, you can then investigate how you might reduce that memory usage.

Comment: What are you doing with your webshots?  You don't show enough code for us to see what  you're actually doing with them.  Are they  accumulating in memory  somehow?  If you show us more code related to what you're doing with them, we would have a better chance of seeing something to fix there.

Comment: Just added the webshot code, thank you! @jfriend00

Comment: OK, the webShot is being saved to a file.  Once that process is done, I see no reason that memory should stay allocated from that (unless there are bugs inside the webShot library).  So, you need to use heapsnapshots over time to see if the memory allocated to node.js is "in use" and allocated by the JS engine or if it's internally free waiting to be reused (not returned to the OS).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll dig into this and see about the heapsnapshots